# How can I make a chat between admin and user in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel at this moment and I want to make a chat between user and admin so anyone can help me? how can I do this?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please read this guide on How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example so we can help you further. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using pusherJs.You Can make chat system using pusherJs

Answer (score 0):

Laravel comes with laravel Echo package  out of the box. You can easily install and configure your web socket server within laravel... & use broadcasting channels to build chat system.. For more refer the docs...

Answer (score 0):

1. In the first step, your need to build a mode with a table in the database

table - `Conversation` [ user_id , admin_id , is_online_user , is_online_admin , is_read]

table `users`

table `admins`

table `message` -  ['body','conversation_id'];

2. create a relation between table
3. create an action controller